# how to read a file with space separated values that are not constant

Tags: python, pandas

```
TIME      M1       M2   K1 K2        SEP    ECC  R1/ROL1 R2/ROL2  TYPE
 0.0000   30.000   15.000  1  1   6.9488e+05  0.00   0.000   0.000  INITIAL 
 0.0000   30.000   15.000  1  1   6.9488e+05  0.00   0.000   0.000  PreMS aperi=694884 t1=0 f1=0 R1=7.74028 R1/RLperi1=2.53155e-05 R1/a(1-e)=1.11389e-05 t2=0 f2=0 R2=5.02787 R2/RLperi2=2.25555e-05 R2/a(1-e)=7.23555e-06 R1+2/aperi=1.83745e-05
 5.9523   27.735   14.912  2  1   7.3335e+05  0.00   0.000   0.000  TYPE_CHNGE
 5.9611   27.663   14.912  4  1   7.3459e+05  0.00   0.004   0.000  TYPE_CHNGE
 6.3588   14.790   14.903  4  1   1.0562e+06  0.00   0.004   0.000  q-inv
 6.4755   10.469   14.901  7  1   1.2381e+06  0.00   0.000   0.000  TYPE_CHNGE
 6.6301    9.158   14.897  8  1   1.3065e+06  0.00   0.000   0.000  TYPE_CHNGE
 6.6595    8.857   14.897 14  1            0 -1.00   0.000   0.000  TYPE_CHNGE
 6.6595    8.857   14.897 14  1            0 -1.00   0.000   0.000  DISRUPT 
 6.6595    8.857   14.897 14  1            0 -1.00   0.000   0.000  SN
 6.6595    8.857   14.897 14  1            0 -1.00   0.000   0.000  kick vk=392.824 vr=1.84982 theta=6.21052 phi=-0.146541 -> vn=390.999

 6.6595    8.857   14.897 14  1            0 -1.00   0.000   0.000  BEG_SYMB
12.7530    8.857   14.654 14  2            0 -1.00   0.000   0.000  OFF_MS
12.7530    8.857   14.654 14  2            0 -1.00   0.000   0.000  TYPE_CHNGE
12.7795    8.857   14.648 14  4            0 -1.00   0.000   0.000  TYPE_CHNGE
14.2105    8.857   10.438 14  5            0 -1.00   0.000   0.000  TYPE_CHNGE
14.2653    8.857    1.912 14 14            0 -1.00   0.000   0.000  TYPE_CHNGE
14.2653    8.857    1.912 14 14            0 -1.00   0.000   0.000  BEG_SYMB
14.2653    8.857    1.912 14 14            0 -1.00   0.000   0.000  q-inv
14.2653    8.857    1.912 14 14            0 -1.00   0.000   0.000  SN
20000.0000    8.857    1.912 14 14            0 -1.00   0.000   0.000  MAX_TIME
```

Probability : 1

This is the file. As you can see the 3rd and 12th row have a variable that is very long and is also separated by spaces but is part of the same "TYPE". 
I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('c_log2.dat', delimiter='delim_whitespace=True').
```

But it complained:

> ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 41 fields in line 12, saw 43

How do I read a file that has long values separated by spaces but part of the same variable?
Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Preprocess into a temporary file, then read that file with pandas.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import re

for_pd = StringIO()
with open('ale.csv') as ale:
    for line in ale:
        line = re.subn(r'\s+', ',', line.strip(), 9)
        print (line[0], file=for_pd)
for_pd.seek(0)

df = pd.read_csv(for_pd)
print (df.head())
```

Output:

```
     TIME      M1      M2  K1  K2        SEP  ECC  R1/ROL1  R2/ROL2  \
0  0.0000  30.000  15.000   1   1   694880.0  0.0    0.000      0.0   
1  0.0000  30.000  15.000   1   1   694880.0  0.0    0.000      0.0   
2  5.9523  27.735  14.912   2   1   733350.0  0.0    0.000      0.0   
3  5.9611  27.663  14.912   4   1   734590.0  0.0    0.004      0.0   
4  6.3588  14.790  14.903   4   1  1056200.0  0.0    0.004      0.0   

                                                TYPE  
0                                            INITIAL  
1  PreMS aperi=694884 t1=0 f1=0 R1=7.74028 R1/RLp...  
2                                         TYPE_CHNGE  
3                                         TYPE_CHNGE  
4                                              q-inv
```